# why did the author choose past simple for something that people used to do before?

Tags: past-tense

How Innovation Works And Why It Flourishes in Freed

> Innovation has made it possible to work for a fraction of a second in order to be able to afford to turn on an electric lamp for an hour, providing the quantity of light that would have required a whole day’s work if you had to make it yourself by collecting and refining sesame oil or lamb fat to burn in a simple lamp, as much of humanity **did** in the not-so-distant past.

Why not ***had done*** if nobody uses these substances (sesame oil or lamb fat) nowadays.

May be it is because it happened  in the not so distant past or may be there are still people that use it.
Or this clause is not so important in this sentence(you can erase it the sentence is still understandable). So there is no use to put it before or after another event.

Comment: It's not ***had done*** because the paragraph starts with *Innovation **has** made it possible...* (the "reference time" is ***now***, not some time in the past). They ***did*** it before ***now***, They ***had done*** it before ***then***.

Answer (score 1):

When you write a past tense narrative, and want to refer to events that occurred before the time of the narrative, or were completed at the time of the narrative, it may be useful to use the past perfect.

> Yesterday I used an oil lamp to light my house.  I'd gone out the week before to collect and refine sesame oil to burn in the lamp.

This narrative is anchored at "Yesterday".  The collection and refinement had been completed at that time, so past perfect is a good fit.

But the example given is a present tense description. It talks about, how (Now) innovation has made life easier.  It then goes on to talk about events that are in the past, and for those it uses the past tense.  But since there is no sense of being complete at the narrative time, there is no need for past perfect.

In general, if in doubt, don't use past perfect.  It is a very rare tense (less than 1% of verbs are in this tense)

Comment: Rumors have abound that this album had been released in Holland and or that there were a small number of white label test pressings in existence but none of these claims have ever been substantiated               In this example have abound  refers to now  and there is a past perfect just after so past perfect is anchored at now

Comment: source or it didn't happen

Comment: a little text written on the back of the sleeve of this record (Protex "strange obsessions" lp) issued on sing sing records . It is not the whole text

Comment: Well it's not grammatically correct, and it is hardly an authoritative source. But it still places a past time "there were white label pressings..." and an event that was complete at that time, the rumoured release in Holland. But this could be rephrased with the past tense "was released" with little change in meaning.  Often you can use a past perfect, but you don't have to. So there is a choice for the writer.  Learners should generally not choose to use the past perfect if the past tense is available, since it makes for tighter writing.

Comment: what will be the change in meaning ?

Comment: Not much difference in this case.

Comment: OK But what will be the difference ?

Comment: Please ask a new question, though the general difference between past and past perfect has been asked about and answered already.

Comment: @user5577  You already asked this question 8 years ago: [Is the past perfect necessary here?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56353/is-the-past-perfect-necessary-here) If the answers did not satisfy you, you can edit the question and include more context with a link to the source: https://boards.vinylcollective.com/topic/26520-sing-sing-records-70s80s-punk-reissue-label/page/2/ The passage / ad **was** posted in 2010, but it seems the record company (Sing Sing Records) **has since gone** bust.

Answer (score 0):

**Did** refers to the past, **had done** to something that happened before a past event.

> I went for a walk in the rain.
>
> I *had put on* my waterproofs before I went out.